# Definition of Specific Heat: Molar Specific or Mass Specific Quantity?

Tags: thermodynamics

Five kilograms of air, initially at 0 °C, are heated until the temperature reaches 50 °C. The internal energy increases by 180 kJ during this process. Find the specific heat of air.

I know this is a basic question, but I am confused on the dimensional analysis. The answer provided is $0.72 \ kJ/kg$. From my textbook we defined specific heat of an ideal gas as:

$$u_1 - u_2 = c (T_2 - T_1)$$

Where $u$ is the specific internal energy (ie: kJ/kmol). They call it a molar specific internal energy.  Thus, the units for specific heat should be $\frac{[kJ]}{[kmol \cdot K]}$. Are these two valid definitions for specific heat? How can I tell which one is of interest ?

Comment: It needs to be explicitly specified which one is being employed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specific values are those normalized to the amount of material (mass in kg or quantity in moles) and are thus useful as material properties. "[Specific heat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_heat_capacity)" typically means the [heat capacity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity) normalized to the mass, but if "molar" is specified, it means the heat capacity normalized to the number of moles ("[molar heat capacity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molar_heat_capacity)" is also used for the latter). One can easily convert from one to the other for a certain material (e.g., the [molar mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molar_mass) of air is 0.02897 kg/mol).